# Code efficiency/performance improvement in Pushshift Reddit web scraping loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, reddit

I am extracting Reddit data via the Pushshift API. More precisely, I am interested in comments and posts (submissions) in subreddit X with search word Y, made from now until datetime Z (e.g. all comments mentioning "GME" in subreddit /rwallstreetbets). All these parameters can be specified. So far, I got it working with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
import time
import json
import sys
import numpy as np

username = ""  # put the username you want to download in the quotes
subreddit = "gme"  # put the subreddit you want to download in the quotes
search_query = "gamestop" # put the word you want to search for (present in comment or post) in the quotes
# leave either one blank to download an entire user's, subreddit's, or search word's history
# or fill in all to download a specific users history from a specific subreddit mentioning a specific word

filter_string = None
if username == "" and subreddit == "" and search_query == "":
    print("Fill in either username or subreddit")
    sys.exit(0)
elif username == "" and subreddit != "" and search_query == "":
    filter_string = f"subreddit={subreddit}"
elif username != "" and subreddit == "" and search_query == "":
    filter_string = f"author={username}"
elif username == "" and subreddit != "" and search_query != "":
    filter_string = f"subreddit={subreddit}&q={search_query}"
elif username == "" and subreddit == "" and search_query != "":
    filter_string = f"q={search_query}"    
else:
    filter_string = f"author={username}&subreddit={subreddit}&q={search_query}"

url = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/{}/?size=500&sort=desc&{}&before="

start_time = datetime.utcnow()

def redditAPI(object_type):
    global df_comments    
    df_comments = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "comment", "score", "id"])
    global df_posts    
    df_posts = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "post", "score", "id"])      

    print(f"\nLooping through {object_type}s and append to dataframe...")

    count = 0
    previous_epoch = int(start_time.timestamp())
    while True:
        # Ensures that loop breaks at March 16 2021 for testing purposes
        if previous_epoch <= 1615849200:
            break
            
        new_url = url.format(object_type, filter_string)+str(previous_epoch)
        json_text = requests.get(new_url)
        time.sleep(1)  # pushshift has a rate limit, if we send requests too fast it will start returning error messages
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(json_text.text)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        if 'data' not in json_data:
            break
        objects = json_data['data']
        if len(objects) == 0:
            break
            
        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(objects)

        for object in objects:
            previous_epoch = object['created_utc'] - 1
            count += 1
            if object_type == "comment":
                    df2.rename(columns={'created_utc': 'date', 'body': 'comment'}, inplace=True)
                    df_comments = df_comments.append(df2[['date', 'comment', 'score']])               
            elif object_type == "submission":
                    df2.rename(columns={'created_utc': 'date', 'selftext': 'post'}, inplace=True)
                    df_posts = df_posts.append(df2[['date', 'post', 'score']])
                    
    # Convert UNIX to datetime
    df_comments["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_comments["date"],unit='s')
    df_posts["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_posts["date"],unit='s')
    
    # Drop blank rows (the case when posts only consists of an image)
    df_posts['post'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
    df_posts.dropna(subset=['post'], inplace=True)
    
    # Drop duplicates (see last comment on https://www.reddit.com/r/pushshift/comments/b7onr6/max_number_of_results_returned_per_query/)
    df_comments = df_comments.drop_duplicates()
    df_posts = df_posts.drop_duplicates()
    print("\nDone. Saved to dataframe.")
```

Unfortunately, I do have some performance issues. Due to the fact that I paginate based on created_utc - 1 (and since I do not want to miss any comments/posts), the initial dataframe will contain duplicates (since there won't be 100 (=API limit) new comments/posts every new second). If I run the code for a long time frame (e.g. current time - 1 March 2021), this will result in a huge dataframe which takes considerably long to process.

As the code is right now, the duplicates are added to the dataframe and only after the loop, they are removed. Is there a way to make this more efficient? E.g. to check within the for loop whether the object already exists in the dataframe? Would this make a difference, performance wise? Any input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this code meant to be runnable as is? I tried it out by setting `username` to some random /r/GME user and calling `redditAPI('submission')`, but it throws `NameError: name 'df_comments' is not defined`

Comment: If you get rid of the if statements at the start of the function that defines the logic for when object_type == X, it should work. I changed it accordingly above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to query the data so that there are no duplicates in the first place.

You are using the `before` parameter of the API, allowing to get only records strictly before the timestamp. This means we can send as `before` on each iteration the timestamp of the earliest record that we already have. In this case in response we are only gonna have records that we haven't seen yet, so no duplicates.

In code that would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import time
import json

def get_data(object_type, username='', subreddit='', search_query='', max_time=None, min_time=1615849200):
    # start from current time if not specified
    if max_time is None:
        max_time = int(time.time())

    # generate filter string
    filter_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(
        {k: v for k, v in zip(
            ['author', 'subreddit', 'q'],
            [username, subreddit, search_query]) if v != ""})

    url_format = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/{}/?size=500&sort=desc&{}&before={}"

    before = max_time
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    while before > min_time:
        url = url_format.format(object_type, filter_string, before)
        resp = requests.get(url)

        # convert records to dataframe
        dfi = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(resp.text)['data'])
        
        if object_type == 'comment':
            dfi = dfi.rename(columns={'created_utc': 'date', 'body': 'comment'})
            df = pd.concat([df, dfi[['id', 'date', 'comment', 'score']]])
        elif object_type == 'submission':
            dfi = dfi.rename(columns={'created_utc': 'date', 'selftext': 'post'})
            dfi = dfi[dfi['post'].ne('')]
            df = pd.concat([df, dfi[['id', 'date', 'post', 'score']]])

        # set `before` to the earliest comment/post in the results
        # next time we call requests.get(...) we will only get comments/posts before
        # the earliest that we already have, thus not fetching any duplicates
        before = dfi['date'].min()

        # if needed
        # time.sleep(1)
        
    return df
```

Testing by getting the comments and checking for duplicate values (by `id`):

```
username = ""
subreddit = "gme"
search_query = "gamestop"

df_comments = get_data(
    object_type='comment',
    username=username,
    subreddit=subreddit,
    search_query=search_query)

df_comments['id'].duplicated().any()    # False
df_comments['id'].nunique()             # 2200
```

Comment: Works with some slight change (dfi = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(resp.text)['data']) instead of using json_normalize). Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped! By the way, just out of curiosity, what was the problem with `json_normalize`? It worked fine in my test, interesting if it fails with something else...

Comment: For me it said that pandas didn't have a built-in module named json_normalize... Didn't really check it cause I knew that df.from_dict works anyway :)

Comment: Ah OK, you probably have some older version of `pandas` then, they moved `json_normalize` to top level in 1.0.0 (January 29, 2020)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a bloom filter to check if values have already been passed through.

There is a package on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/bloom-filter/), which implements this very easily. To use the bloom filter you just have to add a "key" to the filter, this can be a combination of the username and comment. This way you can check if you have already added comments to your data frame. I suggest that you use the bloom filter as early as possible in your method, i.e. after you get a response from the API.